# How can I implement a dynamic checklist with additional comments using MongoDB and rails?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am building a project that involved car servicing. I have an admin panel which allows the creation of services, and each service has a number of checks to perform (The checks themselves and belong to multiple services). The solution looks like this:

```
  class Service
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :price, type: Integer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :checks
end

class Check
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end
```

These checks are performed on an instance '**Appointment**'. So when an appointment is carried out, all the necessary checks are displayed (depending on the type of service).

What is the best way to create and store an instance of these checks? 
In mySQL, I would create an appointment_check table with appointment_id and check_id as a compound key, and have the details of the check in there.

Is this the best way to resolve this in MongoDB? But surely this involves a join..

Is there a solution I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not know the concept of joins. So in your case you would not have a `appointment_check` table, as the has_and_belongs_to_many are just arrays of ids, in both sides.
What I would do in your case, is to have a `belongs_to :appointment` in the Check model, so you can have a `appointment_id` and the `check_id` within the same document.

Comment: Thanks, so where would my instance of the check go? I.E, the record of someone carrying out that check?
I understand that your solution is how to resolve a many to many relationship, but I'm not fully clear on doing this when I have extra data to record regarding that 'connection', or instance.